# What does mean kafka compression-rate-avg

Tags: apache-kafka, compression

I'm running Kafka producer, and looking inside the metric:
**compression-rate-avg**

What does the value mean - the higher value the better compression or the opposite?

My current compression strategy gzip, and producer buffer memory is 32Mb. Each message is 0.5-1M uncompressed
What is the recommended compression configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka/monitoring.html) (always a good place to start):

> compression-rate-avg
>
> The average compression rate of record batches,
> defined as the average ratio of the compressed batch size over the
> uncompressed size.

So smaller is better.

As for which to use see https://developer.ibm.com/articles/benefits-compression-kafka-messaging/ (which took another 30 seconds of googling to find). It has this table:

[image]

Zstd looks good to me.